# What does "this" mean in a nodejs module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, global

I have a simple codes like the following and execute it as a node module:

```
console.log(this);
module.exports = {…};
```

I know that `global` is the default context (like `window` in browsers), but what does the `this` keyword refer to?

Comment: See also the related topics [Meaning of `this` in node.js modules and functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/1048572) and [Difference between `this` in node repl and in module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20861049/1048572)

Comment: For details about node module internals, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28955047/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` (in the context of a module) is the same as `exports` in node.js. However you should generally use `exports`/`module.exports` instead, so that it's explicitly clear what you're modifying.

Comment: Yes,I get that (this===exports) is true,but why does 'console.log(this)' return '{}' always,an empty object?