# Meaning of 'this' in nodejs when using ES6 import/export

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I have a javascript file

1. When I am using es6 import/export and doing

```
console.log(this); // undefined
```

it is giving undefined.

2. When I performed the same thing using require/module.exports

```
console.log(this); // {}
```

it is giving an empty module.exports object.

My question is - Why it is giving undefined in the case of es6 import/export.

Comment: Do you understand what that empty object is in the commonjs module? What do you want the `this` keyword to reference in a module?

Comment: @Bergi - Yes `this` points to `module.exports` object . I was expecting the same with es6 import/export and that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Then the answer is simple: there is no module object in ES6 modules :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ES6 module (using `export` and `import` declarations), the `this` keyword defaults to the value `undefined` - there is no reasonable object it should refer to. This also makes us recognise a lot more mistakes, where you accidentally refer to the `this` of the module (e.g. writing an arrow function in an object literal) but meant to have dynamic `this` or something else - the code breaks upon accessing a property on `undefined`, instead of accessing a property on some other object.
If you want to reference the global object from a module, explicitly use [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) instead.

In a CommonJS module (using `module.exports` and `require()`), it refers to the module object - see [What does "this" mean in a nodejs module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058814/what-does-this-mean-in-a-nodejs-module) or [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/1048572).