# JavaScript global scope in terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code:

```
function foo(){
    console.log(this.a);
}

var a = 2;

foo();
```

The code above gives `2` when run in browser console. I run the same code in the terminal by doing `node up-and-going.js` and got `undefined`.

What am I missing?

PS: I'm new to JavaScript.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The "default" scope/context in nodejs is different

Comment: @charlieftl bad dupe, nodejs isnt mentioned at all

Comment: @JonasW. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861049/this-different-between-repl-and-script
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058814/what-does-this-mean-in-a-nodejs-module
  [Meaning of "this" in node.js modules and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770299/1048572)?

Comment: I understand that in a browser, the `this` in my example refers to the browser global variable `window` since the function `foo();` was invoked globally. Can anyone tell me if I get it right?

Comment: @JonasW. any feedback on my comment?

Comment: @lomse yes, but that works differently in nodejs