# 'this' behaves differently in node environment than browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, executioncontext

I am following along with a tutorial about `this` and [execution context](https://codeburst.io/js-demystified-04-execution-context-97dea52c8ac6). I observed that this code executes properly in the Chrome Console:

```
var globalThis = this

function myFunc () {  
  console.log('globalThis: ', globalThis)
  console.log('this inside: ', this)
  console.log(globalThis === this)
}

myFunc()

// globalThis: Window {...}
// this inside: Window {...}
// true
```

However, when I try to execute this same code in a node environment, I get this as a response:

```
globalThis:  {}

this inside:  { console: [Getter],
  global: [Circular],
  process: 
   process {
     title: 'node',
     version: 'v8.16.2',
     ...

false
```

I understand that the global node `this` value should be different from the browser javascript `this` value, but the question is, why does `myFunc's this` value not equal the global value?

Comment: When I run your code in Node, I get `true`, they're the same

Comment: interesting, any idea why it might be returning `false` for me?

Comment: I get false - so perhaps it's dependant on the version of node (false on 13.x) ... or how you run it ... I get true if running as repl ... and this inside is different again when `'use strict';`

Comment: I'm on v12.13.0. Sounds pretty weird for `globalThis` to be an empty object, does it inherit from anything?

Comment: using `var globalThis = global` works different again

Comment: Not the same in Node for me.

Comment: try `console.log(this);` outside the function .. this is `{}` - therefore, `this` is not the same as `global` in the global scope :p

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861049/this-different-between-repl-and-script

Comment: some more basic investigation for you ... `({}).toString.call(this)` ===  `[object Object]` ... `({}).toString.call(global)` === `[object global]`  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the global scope of a node module is the same module, so if you execute `console.log(this)` outside your function you are referencing the global scope of an empty module which is an empty object `{}`, but when you execute the same `console.log(this)` inside your function `this` is going to point to the global Node scope (contains what you are seeing: console, global, process and a lot of other stuff), now if you are on strict mode, the scope inside of your function should be `undefined` as it doesn't have a default local scope defined.

Its a lot simpler on your browser where the global scope is the `Window` object.