# this.property in a free function call works in my browser console and NodeJS REPL, but not when running as a NodeJS script. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, visual-studio-code, this

I'm studying about the 'this' keyword inside regular function and arrow function, so following examples in Stack Overflow I think that I had understood that, but one detail left unsolved for me. Please help me with that.
I don't know why but when I test the below code using `node myScript.js` the result is `undefined`, while using Fiddle or Chrome or Firefox the result is the expected.

As I had read, because of the `fo2` function is called without bind any object so its 'this' keyword refers to global object, and 'hi' should be printed. It doesn't happen using `node myScript.js` but yes using Browser Console or Fiddle.
I don't use `console.log()` inside the functions to avoid returning `undefined`, as it has been explained before in other Stack Overflow answers.

This is the code;

```
var greeting = 'hi';

const obj = {
  greeting: 'hey',

  fo() {
    const greeting = 'hello';

      function fo2 () {
        return this.greeting;
      };
      
      return fo2();  
  }  
};

console.log(obj.fo()); // 'hi' using browser console and Fiddle, but undefined using `node myScript.js`
```

I'm using NodeJS 18.12.1.

Comment: Just want to confirm that you understand that you're invoking `fo2()` without providing an object.  compare your `return fo2()` to `return this.fo2()`

Comment: @Wyck indeed, that'd make a difference. But let's please not change the question at this point, which clearly asks about what's causing "hi" in one context, and "undefined" in another. If that's a mistake, that should be its own question.

Comment: @Wyck Thanks to the answer of **user**,  i was doing some changes, just for curiosity, trying to get the correct out in node terminal (**fo2()** bound the global object) and it got there using **"type":"commonjs"** in package.json and assigning the _greeting_ top variable like **globalThis.greeting = 'hi'**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here.

One is that when you run a script like `node myScript.js`, the script is run as a "module". If your package.json has `"type": "commonjs"`, or doesn't specify the `"type"` field, it is run as a CommonJS module. If your package.json has `"type": "module"`, it is run as a ECMAScript module. ([related docs](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type)). That is, if you're using `.js` as a file extension. If you use `.cjs`, NodeJS will treat it as a CommonJS module, and if you use `.mjs`, NodeJS will treat it as a ECMAScript module. ([related docs](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system)).

See also ['this' different between REPL and script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20861049/11107541). The TL;DR is that with a CommonJS Module, the code in the module is run as if it were wrapped in the following:

```
var ctx = {};
(function(exports) {
    // your code
    console.log(this === globalThis); // false
}).call(ctx, ctx);
```

But if you run NodeJS in REPL mode (just run `node` in your system console), then `this === globalThis` is `true`, and variables declared with `var` at the "top level scope" will be placed in the `globalThis` object, just like they are in the browser console (where `globalThis` is synonymous with the global `window` object).

In your browser console, you get "hi" because the function where you `console.log(this.greeting)` is called without being given a specific `this`, so it falls back to `globalThis`. But in ECMAScript module contexts (Ex. NodeJS scripts run with a package.json with `"type": "module"`, or web `<script module>` (module scripts)), the `this` at the top-level is always `undefined`.

Another thing is that if you don't specify [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), JavaScript will typically be run in ["sloppy mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode) by default, where `this` is never `undefined`. Strict mode is usually opt-in, but in a ECMAScript module context, strict mode is the default. That's why you're getting `undefined` when running `node myScript.js` when you'd actually be getting an error if you did something to enable strict mode.

Here's what it would look like "behind the scenes" to run a CommonJS module with strict mode enabled (if you were to put `"use strict";` at the top of your script file):

```
let ctx = {};
(function() {
  "use strict";
  function a(){
    console.log(this.foo);
  }
  a(); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foo')
}).call(ctx);
```

You'd get the same error running the above code without explicitly using `"use strict";` if you put `"type": "module"` in your package.json.

More readings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.