# Unexpected global objects in node 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, this, global

When executing with node v18.17.1, why are there different versions of the global object?

```js
function foobar() { return this; }

console.log(this); // {}
console.log(foobar()); // Large output, as below:

/*
<ref *1> Object [global] {
  global: [Circular *1],
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Getter]
  },
...
*/
```

Comment: The long code sample is pretty irrelevant to the question, isn't it?

Comment: It seems correct - it's the global object. Are you saying all the other logs that are marked as `// global` return something different? Or otherwise why is `.f5()` specifically unexpected?

Comment: @VLAZ The lines marked `// global` except for `.f5()` return this as the global object:
`{ name: 'global' }`

Comment: @Beyers `console.log(this);` is not logging the global object if executed in a module (not as a script)

Comment: @Bergi Could you expand on your comment please?

Comment: @Beyers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861049/this-different-between-repl-and-script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25058814/what-does-this-mean-in-a-nodejs-module